# Can I combine multiple Feats if they all require a standard attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats

I have a Ranger with Pinpoint Targeting, Deadly Aim, Focused Shot, and Vital Strike.  Can I make 1 standard attack action and use all of them together?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80152/8610).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So far as I know, when you take a feat, or any other ability/feature, that requires a specific action, you can't combine other actions that utilize the same action.

- Pinpoint Targeting: Standard Action
- Focused Shot: Standard Action
- Vital Strike: During an Attack Action
- Deadly Aim: Before you make an Attack Roll [Like Power Attack]

Thus, you can only choose to either Pinpoint Targeting, Vital Strike or Focused Shot for a **Standard Action** (Which includes Attack Actions).

You can however use Deadly Aim with any of those, as they are basically added during the rolling, and not tied to an 'Action'

A relevant quote from [d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat):

> Some combat options (such as using the Cleave feat) are standard actions that allow you to make an attack, but don't count as the attack action. These options can't be combined with other standard actions or options that modify only attack actions (such as Vital Strike). Source: PPC:MTT

Another relevant quote from [Paizo.com](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9pyy): (provided by *Hey I Can Chan*)

> **Vital Strike: Can I use this with Spring Attack, or on a charge?**
>
> No. Vital Strike can only be used as part of an attack action, which is a specific kind of standard action. Spring Attack is a special kind of full-round action that includes the ability to make one melee attack, not one attack action. Charging uses similar language and can also not be used in combination with Vital Strike.

Answer (score 6):

#### [Pinpoint Targeting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pinpoint-targeting-combat---final), [Focused Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/focused-shot-combat), and [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat---final) typically can't be combined with each other, but any one of those *can* be combined with [Deadly Aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat)

When a description says that a creature can take a standard action to do something, it means that the creature must take a separate, discrete standard action to do it. The creature *can't* put a bunch of things in a pile that all take standard actions to use then do them *all* using the *same* standard action. (Anyway, the ranger wouldn't want this to work like that: If it did, a wizard could cast *all* of his spells that have a casting time of 1 standard action in *the same* 1 standard action, and the ranger would die a lot.)

Anyway, here's a rundown of how these are phrased:

- The feat [Pinpoint Targeting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pinpoint-targeting-combat---final) says, "As a standard action, make a single ranged attack."
- The feat [Focused Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/focused-shot-combat) says, "As a standard action, you may make an attack with a bow or crossbow and add your Intelligence modifier on the damage roll."
- The feat [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat---final) says, "When you use the attack action, you can make one attack at your highest base attack bonus that deals additional damage," and [the FAQ says that a creature must take a standard action](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9pyy) to realize this feat's benefit.

But, because it has no associated action, the feat [Deadly Aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat) can be combined with pretty much anything if the creature's willing to suffer the penalties.

Comment: I wasn't sure but I had a feeling they had to be separate.  As to the wizard, that comparison doesn't actually line up, because in my case they all say one attack, they just modify that one attack, each spell cast is clearly a different action for each, as they would have different verbal, somatic, and possibly component requirements, unless you are able to speak multiple words at once, have 6 arms, and pouches upon pouches of components.

Comment: @Pethrax What's the difference between casting simultaneously two different spells and, as the question supposes, attacking simultaneously in two different ways?

Answer (score 0):

> **Vital strike**
>
> Prerequisites: Base attack bonus +6.
>
> Benefit: When you use the attack action, you can make one attack at
> your highest base attack bonus that deals additional damage. Roll the
> weapon’s damage dice for the attack twice and add the results together
> before adding bonuses from Strength, weapon abilities (such as
> flaming), precision-based damage, and other damage bonuses. These
> extra weapon damage dice are not multiplied on a critical hit, but are
> added to the total.

This one works wherever you take the attack action. A specific type of standard action.

> **Pinpoint Targeting**
>
> Prerequisites: Dex 19, Improved Precise Shot, Point-Blank Shot, Precise Shot, base attack bonus +16.
>
> Benefit: As a Prerequisites: Dex 13, base attack bonus +1.
>
> Benefit: As a standard action, make a single ranged attack. The target does not gain any armor, natural armor, or shield bonuses to its Armor Class. You do not gain the benefit of this feat if you move this round.

This one denotes a special action specifically for this feat.

> **Deadly Aim**
>
> Prerequisites: Dex 13, base attack bonus +1.
>
> Benefit: You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all ranged attack rolls to gain a +2 bonus on all ranged damage rolls. When your base attack bonus reaches +4, and every +4 thereafter, the penalty increases by –1 and the bonus to damage increases by +2. You must choose to use this feat before making an attack roll and its effects last until your next turn. The bonus damage does not apply to touch attacks or effects that do not deal hit point damage.

This one works whenever you make a ranged attack.

> **Focused shot**
>
> Benefit: As a standard action, you may make an attack with a bow or crossbow and add your Intelligence modifier on the damage roll. You must be within 30 feet of your target to deal this extra damage. Creatures immune to critical hits and sneak attacks are immune to this extra damage.

This one also is activated as a standard action.

Deadly Aim is the only one that is able to be combined with any of the other feats. Vital strike triggers whenever you make the attack action, so it has the largest potential to be combined. The other two require their own standard actions to activate so they are unable to combine with each other or vital strike.