# Can you use Double Strike Feat as part of full attack action given enough extra attack/s for two weapon fighting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you use Double Strike Feat as part of full attack action given enough extra attack/s for two weapon fighting? Meaning, if you have enough attacks, can you then make pairs of attacks (primary hand and off-hand) using one attack roll for each pair of attacks?

EX: Str 18/+4, BAB +8/+3 with Two Weapon Fighting & Improved Two Weapon Fighting

1. Normal Two Weapon full attack would be at +10/+10/+7/-1 (please proof)
2. Then with Double Strike wouldn't be +10/+7 but four attacks occur?

[Double Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/ascension-games-llc/combat-feats/double-strike-combat/)

Comment: Your Full Attack would be +10/+10(off hand)/+7/+7(offhand Improved TWF) assuming a light 2nd weapon.

Comment: Idk how you got down to -1

Comment: My mistake. Hence I asked for a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Double Strike is its own standard action. It cannot be combined with any other action of any kind. Only non-action effects (e.g. Power Attack) can be combined with it.

Other actions can have effects that last, and can affect future actions like Double Strike—for example, *true strike* takes its own standard action, and applies a +20 bonus to your next attack. If your next action is the first attack in a Double Strike action, then that attack gets the +20 bonus from *true strike*. This is **totally different** from what you are describing, however: you are not mixing the actions together at all. You are just benefiting from some temporary bonus provided by *true strike*.

This is because actions themselves **never** happen at the same time. If two different things say “As a (not-free)<sup>1</sup> action, you do this,” and there is no lingering effect or bonus from either, those two things can never benefit from one another. So when Double Strike says “As a standard action, you can make one attack with both your primary and secondary weapons (or with both ends of a double weapon),” and full-attack says “you must use a full-round action to get your additional attacks,” you know those two things can never, ever, happen at the same time. The rules, effects, bonuses, penalties, and so on from each never affects the other in *any* way.

So if you are using a standard action for Double Strike, you are *not* using a full-round action for a full attack, by definition. Likewise, if you *are* using a full-round action for a full attack, you are *not* using a standard action for Double Strike, again by definition. There is absolutely no way around this. Even if you somehow had more actions in a single turn, you would have to do one first, then the other, not both at once. Any exception would have to be completely explicit, something like

> When you make a full attack with the two-weapon fighting option, your first attack can be replaced by the two attacks Double Strike usually performs as a standard action. If you do this, you [figure out how the penalties work because it’s spelled out for you in this ability that lets you do this thing you normally could not do].

Note that no such effect actually exists in the game at this time. But you can see a similar example in the initial benefits of the [Greatsword Battler divine fighting technique](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/divine-fighting-technique-combat/#TOC-Greatsword-Battler-), which allows you to use Vital Strike (normally only applying to the particular standard action known as Attack) at the end of a charge (usually a full-round action independent of the Attack action).

1. <sub>Some free actions are explicitly allowed to occur during some other types of actions. For example, talking is allowed pretty much no matter what you’re doing. Five-foot steps are allowed between attacks in a full attack. Etc. Such exceptions are always explicitly described by the rules for the free action in question. Non-free actions never have these kinds of exceptions. Ultimately,
   these exceptions are not particularly relevant to this question.</sub>

Comment: @Ifusaso I mean, that *is* true—you can’t use actions simultaneously. You could use a swift or move action before the standard action, and then that swift or move action could apply some lingering bonus that applies to the subsequent standard action, but you can’t use them simultaneously, and if the effects of that swift or move action apply only to that action, then no dice on combining it with Double Strike. Free actions get a bit wonky there, though.

Comment: Meaning that if you have the feat and want to do a full attack action, you would roll for each attack with its appropriate penalties right; not like you can Double Strike one pair of attacks and tow separate ones at -2 /-2 each and -5 if any extra attacks left over with Imp 2 Wep.

Comment: @Ifusaso....IDK. But there should or might be instances where swift action could boost Double Strike. Path of War's Boosts and Stances are mostly swift actions. That can drastically add some damage to the feat.

Comment: I was being more broad... I know the intent of your answer, but the wording makes it sound like you couldn't also move on the turn. @Jhyarelle the idea is you're either Full Attacking *or* Double Striking. The difference is largely semantic because the have the same penalty... But Double Strike doesn't add attacks if you're Full Attacking

Comment: @Ifusaso I never mention “turn” anywhere in the answer at all, and I think sloppy wording/thinking like that is *exactly* what the problem is.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver No, you are not *combining* the actions *at all, ever, anywhere in the system, including with third-party content*. Actions are *always* separate. The effect of an action can *last*, as in the case of *Path of War* boosts and stances (which generally last for a turn, or a round, or until you leave the stance), and other actions made during that duration can benefit from the lingering effects—but you are not using that action *while* using another. You are not combining them at all.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver But Double Strike’s effect doesn’t last at all. It allows you to take a standard action, and attack twice. That’s it. Outside of that singular standard action, it has no effect of any kind whatsoever. Its effects do not linger, do not combine with any other action.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver (You may be interested in, for example, [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80152/8610))